# is it possible to print everything in total instead of printing the percentage of every action

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, random, range

I tried to code a coinToss simulator which was pretty easy for a beginner but then, I tried implementing a percentage system that calculates how much percentage of the total flips were heads or tails. That's when I noticed that i'm stuck and that I probably need some help.

I tried breaking the for loop and excluding everything from x variable to print

```
import random


heads = "Heads"
tails = "Tails"
flips = int(input("How many flips do you want to toss?: "))
print("................................")
cointoss = [(heads), (tails)]


for flips in range(flips):
    toss = random.choice(cointoss)
    print(toss)
    X = toss.count(heads)
    Y = toss.count(tails)
    Z = 100/(int(X)+int(Y))
    print('Percent of X: '+str(X*Z)+'%')
    print('Percent of Y: '+str(Y*Z)+'%')
```

this is the result

```
How many flips do you want to toss?: 4
................................
Heads
Percent of X: 100.0%
Percent of Y: 0.0%
Heads
Percent of X: 100.0%
Percent of Y: 0.0%
Heads
Percent of X: 100.0%
Percent of Y: 0.0%
Tails
Percent of X: 0.0%
Percent of Y: 100.0%
```

I want the code to show the total percentage of the whole loop instead of it showing 100% for either heads or tails based on the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are not calculating the percentage correctly as you are not maintaining a count of the current number of spins as you proceed. What you can do is use the current index of the spin to calcultate the percentage in which:

percentageOfHeads = currentNumberOfHeads / currentNumberOfFlips * 100

percentageOfTails = currentNumberOfTails / currentNumberOfFlips * 100

```
import random

heads = "Heads"
tails = "Tails"
numHeads = 0
numTails = 0
flips = int(input("How many flips do you want to toss?: "))
print("................................")
cointoss = [heads, tails]


for flip in range(flips):
    toss = random.choice(cointoss)

    if toss == heads:
        numHeads += 1
    else:
        numTails += 1

    print("Flip #" + str(flip + 1) + ": " + toss)

    percentHeads = numHeads / (flip + 1) * 100
    percentTails = numTails / (flip + 1) * 100

    print('Percent of Heads: ' + str(percentHeads) + '%')
    print('Percent of Tails: ' + str(percentTails) + '%')
```

Comment: This made me think out of the box as I really was stuck. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```
import random

Headcount=0
Tailcount=0
heads = "Heads"
tails = "Tails"
flips = int(input("How many flips do you want to toss?: "))
print("................................")
cointoss = [(heads), (tails)]


for flips in range(flips):
    toss = random.choice(cointoss)
    If toss == heads:
        Headcount+=1
    else:
        Tailcount+=1
    print(toss)
    X = Headcount
    Y = Tailcout
    print('Percent of X: '+str((X/X+Y)*100)+'%')
    print('Percent of Y: '+str((Y/Y+X)*100)+'%')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some extra variables that will count the total number of heads and tails so far, as well as counting the current number of flips done so far. The way you have it now you don't have any info on the total number of heads/tails seen so far, only the result of the current flip, so you can't calculate the percentage accurately.

I'd suggest adding variables outside the loop for total number of heads and total number of tails. Whenever you make a flip you increment the appropriate counter, and then you can calculate the percentage of overall heads/tails based on those counters.